# Instagram API follow user from app not working

Tags: java, android, facebook, instagram

I've been working with instagram API for a while. Since there is no official documentation for changing relationship between users, I've found something on StackOverflow. It is an old answer, and I am not sure if this is even possible now. Can anyone tell me if there is error with my code or this functionality is just disabled by Instagram? I know some apps which are able to follow directly from the app, so I would like to know a way to do that in my app.

Here is my function for following:

```
public void follow(String userID){
    String followURL = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+ userID +"/relationship?action=unfollow&access_token=" + instagramData.getString(InstagramData.LONG_ACCESS_TOKEN);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, followURL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            if (response != null) {

                Log.d(tag, response.toString());

            } else Log.d(tag, "Null");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
            if (error instanceof ServerError && response != null) {
                try {
                    String res = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers, "utf-8"));
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(res);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                    Log.d(tag, e1.toString());
                } catch (JSONException e2) {
                    Log.d(tag, e2.toString());
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(tag, "error");
            }
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

UserID and AccessToken are okay for sure.

Comment: That looks like the old IG APIs, which have been completely shut down by now, https://www.instagram.com/developer/ And the new APIs Facebook provides do not offer that functionality.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. 

However, there are still some applications where you can follow/unfollow users directly. How can that be done? Some 3rd party service or?

Comment: They probably reverse engineered how this functionality works on the website or in the official mobile apps then.

Comment: How that can be done? May I please you for few fundamental instructions so I can figure it out? Thanks in advance!